# magento2.0 failed Installation & Varnish Test after submitting to the market place

Tags: php, magento

I submitted an extension on Magento Marketplace, but it failed the installation and varnished the test with a report that states as follows:

- Environment: PHP 7.1.22 Magento 2.3 CE

  ```
  php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
  ```

  > Enabling maintenance mode
  >   Starting compilation
  >   Something went wrong while compiling generated code. See the error log for details.
  >   Disabling maintenance mode
  >   Command returned non-zero exit code:

  ```
  /usr/bin/php -f /var/www/html/bin/magento setup:di:compile
  ```

**and**

- Environment: PHP 7.2.10 Magento 2.3 CE

  ```
  php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
  ```

  > Enabling maintenance mode
  >   Starting compilation
  >   Something went wrong while compiling generated code. See the error log for details.
  >   Disabling maintenance mode
  >   Command returned non-zero exit code:

  ```
  /usr/bin/php -f /var/www/html/bin/magento setup:di:compile
  ```

However, I can report success for the following configurations:

- Environment: PHP 7.0.31 Magento 2.0 CE
- Environment: PHP 7.0.31 Magento 2.1 CE
- Environment: PHP 7.1.22 Magento 2.2 CE
- Environment: PHP 7.0.31 Magento 2.2 CE
- Environment: PHP 5.6.37 Magento 2.0 CE
- Environment: PHP 5.5.38 Magento 2.0 CE
- Environment: PHP 5.6.37 Magento 2.1 CE

Comment: did you get your solution?

Comment: yes @MohitRane,  downloaded the failed PHP and Magento which my extension failed for, tested locally (on my machine), and resubmitted.

Comment: okay, thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the extension prevents product and category pages from being cached by Varnish. One possible cause is using **cacheable="false"** in one or more blocks on product and category pages.

Additional resources:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish.html